# How to represent an equation with multiple parameters on dynamic graph in mathematica?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, formatting

I work on this equation:

E=x(X)*y(Y)*z(Z)((1-a)*r+a(r-S))

Where a is probability [0, 1], r the anticipated wealth and S a monetary sanction and where x(X), y(Y), z (Z) are decreasing in X, Y, Z and takes values from 0 to 1. Large values of X, Y, Z produce values of x(X), y(Y), z (Z) close to zero and hence reduce the expected utility to nothing. On the other hand, result in values of x(X), y(Y), z (Z) close to one and so hardly affect expected utility.

suppose x(X), y(Y), z (Z) are all egal to 0 so E=0 even if I supppose r=100, S=20 and probability is a=0.5. So I want to simulate with other value (random for example) and see result on dynamic graph

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What have you tried? There are many excellent examples of `Manipulate` in the documentation and on this site. Should get you through.

Comment: I don't know if I must use Manipulate at first to simulate different numerical value of my parameters

Comment: Reading the question it appears that `X`, `Y` and `Z` are functions and `a`, `r` and `S` are numbers. I am not sure if that is correct. You need to at a minimum show the functions and the range (you did this for `a`) of the other numbers. Maybe show one or two minimal examples. Doubtless you will get some help if you can clarify the question.

Comment: @JackLaVigne : suppose x(X), y(Y), z (Z) takes values from 0 to 1. Suppose are all egal to 0 so E=0 even if I supppose r=100, S=20 and probability is a=0.5. So I want to simulate with other value (random for example) and see result on dynamic graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `Manipulate` below you can select any value for the `abscissa` to see how that variable effects the result (Note: this is a bruce force method. I am sure one could make something more elegant).

You can manually change with the slider the values of the other variables as you observe the plot for a particular selection of the `abscissa`.

```
 Manipulate[
 Labeled[
  Switch[
   abscissa,
   "x",
   Plot[x y z ((1 - a) r + a (r - s)), {x, 0, 1},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 100}}],
   "y",
   Plot[x y z ((1 - a) r + a (r - s)), {y, 0, 1},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 100}}],
   "z",
   Plot[x y z ((1 - a) r + a (r - s)), {y, 0, 1},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 100}}],
   "a",
   Plot[x y z ((1 - a) r + a (r - s)), {a, 0, 1},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 100}}],
   "r",
   Plot[x y z ((1 - a) r + a (r - s)), {r, 50, 100},
    PlotRange -> {{50, 100}, {0, 100}}],
   "s",
   Plot[x y z ((1 - a) r + a (r - s)), {s, 10, 30},
    PlotRange -> {{10, 30}, {0, 100}}]
   ],
  {abscissa, "E"}, {Bottom, Left}
  ],
 {{abscissa, "a"}, {"x", "y", "z", "a", "r", "s"}, 
  ControlType -> SetterBar},
 {{x, 0.8}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{y, 0.8}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{z, 0.8}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{a, 0.5}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r, 70}, 50, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{s, 20}, 10, 30, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @JackLaVigneYes I want to see the variation of E. but I want to see as well impact of X Y Z with different value between [0, 1] on E

Comment: ok its good. can add some color effect and filled for each variable and indicate  visualy on the graph or next value of E? 
 
@JackLaVigne

Comment: @GarudaIkëtum The abscissa label changes when you change a variable.

Comment: yes maybe add some effect (color...) will be good and see numerical final value of E on a case @JackLaVigne